# C# console with MVC3 - Call MVC action method from console application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, console

I am working on one C# console application which create List collection of class object now I want to send that object to one mvc3 application (another project) action method.
But when i add reference of mvc3 application to my console application it show some warning and error that are as follows :

> Warning   1   The referenced assembly "MVC_POP3" could not be resolved
>   because it has a dependency on "System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the
>   currently targeted framework
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Please remove references
>   to assemblies not in the targeted framework or consider retargeting
>   your project. Console_Gmail_POP3
>
> Error 4   The type or namespace name 'MVC_POP3' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   D:\Users\Rajendra\TASKs\Console_Gmail_POP3\Console_Gmail_POP3\Program.cs    13  7   Console_Gmail_POP3

So is it possible that i call mvc action method from my console application ?

Please guide me regarding this....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the .NET framework of your console application from client profile to full .NET 4

Steps:

- Right click on your console project, select **Properties**
- **Application** > **Target framework**
- Select **.NET Framework 4** instead of **.NET Framework 4 Client Profile**

[image]